# AQGridView not linking

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, aqgridview

I am trying to use the AQGridView in an app. I copied all the files into my project but I keep getting the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AQGridView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GridViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AQGridViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GridViewCell in GridViewCell.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AQGridViewCell", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GridViewCell in GridViewCell.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong? I have all the necessary files added

Comment: Also i have the QuartzCore framework already imported

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all the `AQGridView` files from your project and then add them again, but make sure when adding the `Add to targets` checkbox before your build target is checked. It seems that the files are added correctly, but not properly linked to your target.